# Increasing length of and passing array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an assignment that requires us to use arrays and not lists. I have two problems right now; one being that every time the user makes an input, the length of array `playerNumber` increases by one so I need it to be indefinite and I also need to send the array back to the main method. The code below works only once and when I try to enter a second input the program crashes.

```
int x = 0;
string answer = "yes";
string[] playerNumber = new string[] {};
while (answer == "yes")
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number   :   ");
    string y = Console.ReadLine();
    playerNumber = new string[] { y };  
    playerNumber[x - 1] = y;
    x++;
    Console.Write("Enter another number   :   ");
    answer = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: you need `Array.Resize` method here

Comment: Can I return this array back to the main method and how?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your'e trying to do.
To start with, your index is out of bounds.
Your'e doing: `playerNumber[x-1]`, but `x == 0`, so you get an exception. This is the only reason your code fails. Note that taking the `++x;` one line up will also fail you, since in the second loop, `playerNumber` is again an array of size 1, but `x` value is now `2`, and your'e again out of bounds.

Secondly, your'e initializing your array both outside and inside the `while` loop. You have no use of the outer initialization (and maybe there's no need for the inner one - again, depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve).

Thirdly, you should give the user the correct instruction: If you want `answer` to be `yes` or `no`, specify it in your `Console.Write`.

So if I managed to guess what you were trying to do, here's your code with a few changes, including the usage of `Array.Resize` (*which is very inefficient in this context*), and returning the array, as you asked:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static string[] MyFunc()
    {
        int x = 1;
        string answer = "yes";

        string[] playerNumber = new string[x];
        while (answer == "yes")
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number   :   ");
            string y = Console.ReadLine();

            playerNumber[x-1] = y;
            x++;
            Array.Resize(ref playerNumber, x);

            Console.Write("Would you like to enter another number? (yes/no)");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        return playerNumber;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyFunc()[0]); // prints the first string

    }
}
```

Comment: It's alright now. I got it working the way I want using the resize method someone told me about. I also find it better to use a do while loop instead of a while loop on its own.

Comment: How did you approach the IndexOutOfRangeException? As I said, that was your main problem. And did you read my answer? It has some more information, including the mentioning of Array.Resize, too, and its inefficiency in this context.

Comment: I stated the value of x as 1 at the start and when a name was entered by the user it would be placed at x-1. Afterwards I added 1 to the value of x and using the Array.Resize method, I changed the length of the array to be that of x so the user could enter as many inputs as they pleased.